# Is there a word for taking action on someone else's behalf against their judgement

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that's similar to *patronizing* but without the negative implications.

Just the action of taking on oneself the responsibility of making a decision for another adult without (or in spite of) their contrary input.

It was [missing word] of you to throw away the rest of my Doritos because you think they're bad for me.

Comment: It was 'very take charge' of you. The words are neutral, but I can't say them with a straight face, that is, without sarcasm.

Comment: I think it's difficult to avoid negative implications because the act of (for example) throwing someone's food away against their wishes is a pretty negative act.

Comment: @CanadianYankee - yeah - I should come up with a better example. It's more about making decisions on someone else's behalf that are meant to be for their benefit, with no malice. So maybe hiding the doritos or refusing to buy the doritos in the first place? The point being that there's denial of agency by the actor. In a similar way to how a parent might make decisions on behalf of a child.

Comment: *Paternalistic* might be close to what you want.  It can sound negative, but that's because it's almost always negative for one adult to treat another adult as a child.

Comment: **Presumptive**?

Comment: Presumptive sounds much better than Fascist, but that's what you would here more often. *Imperious* and *self righteous* are other options. There is nothing approaching neutral because the behavior is patently evil. "... the action of taking on oneself the responsibility of making a decision for another adult" is typically regarded as criminal misconduct.

Comment: @CanadianYankee I think Paternalistic fits the bill perfectly. Yes - it's mildly negative, but only in so far as you don't want to treat other adults as children. It's perfect for my use so I'm happy to give you the green checkmark if you offer it as an actual answer.

Comment: @PhilSweet - I take your point but I think there's a huge chasm between being presumptive about and acting on someone else's behalf based on those presumptions... and fascism.

Comment: @Decapitated Soul Isn't 'presumptuous' the more common variant? I was about to give it as an answer, but you have precedence. I'll do the usual check for duplicates.

Comment: The duplicate offers 'presumptuous' and 'officious'.

Answer (score 0):

I would look to corporate language, which seeks to be morally neutral, and often has to describe actions by one person on behalf of another.

Nouns and noun phrases come to mind first, like “agent” (not in the spy-novel sense, but in the [principal-agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal%E2%80%93agent_problem) sense), or to make an “[executive decision](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=executive%20decision)”, which is what one typically does when the input from another, or a group, is conflicting, or unavailable.  Obviously you’d have to rephrase your example sentences to accommodate a noun, so something like

> “You were [acting as my agent/taking an executive action] when
> you threw those Doritos out, because you think they are bad for
> me”.

The best single adjective that comes to mind is “managerial”, which still has a sense of the other person being in charge of another (rather than merely acting on their behalf). However, it is more neutral than “patronizing”, since "manager" connotes less moral judgement on whether the manager justifiably has the power to so act.

I cannot think of, or find in a thesaurus easily, an adjective form of “agent”, which would be ideal here.